# Show length for surrounding edges as well

Tags: modeling, mesh

With edge length displaying enabled I can see the length of the currently selected edges. Is there a way I can show the length of all edges without selecting them all?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While transforming the lengths of connected edges will show.

But there is no way to make them display at all times.